# Получить список из количества элементов меньших каждого следующего элемента

Tags: python

Есть список.

Как получить список того же размера, где на месте каждого элемента стояло бы количество элементов, меньших по индексу, т.е. левее, и по значению?

То есть, например, для списка:

```
[1,3,6,7,4,2,8,5]
```

это будет список:

```
[0,1,2,3,2,1,6,4]
```

Первым элементом результирующего списка будет 0, т.к. в исходном списке слева нет элементов меньше 1. Вторым - 1, т.к. левее 3 в исходном списке 1 элемент меньше 3 и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 = [1,3,6,7,4,2,8,5]  
l2 = []

for i, item in enumerate(l1):
    l2.append(len([ n+1 for n in l[0:i] if n<l1[i]]))

print(l2)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что внутреннее представление `True == 1`, а `False == 0` и просуммировать результаты сравнения:

```
l2 = [sum(l1[i] > x for x in l1[:i]) for i in range(len(l1))]
print(l2)
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 4]
```